# Is the EV3RSTORM from Lego Mindstorms programmable using a real programming language?

Tags: ev3, programming

I'm a software developer and Lego fan. I'll create a robot with Lego Mindstorms, but I'll like to know that the is EV3RSTORM is programable using a real programming language *(Python, C#, JavaScript, etc.)*.

I don't like the brick system because it's too 'easy' for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EV3 brick runs a linux kernel so it is extremely compatible with many different programming languages. 3rd-party support packages for basically any language you can think of have been made, and most are very mature by this point. A quick google search can come up with some of these. [This previous post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8597/what-are-the-programming-languages-that-can-be-used-on-lego-mindstorm-ev3), among many others on this site, can help point you in the right direction.

In summary, [EV3Dev](https://www.ev3dev.org/) is always a good starting point - the framework is kind of a catch-all of the various programming languages available. [LeJOS](http://lejos.org/) (Java) is a big step up in terms of features (and is generally higher performance than an on-brick Python interpreter, for example). The highest performance solution is probably [EV3RT](http://ev3rt-git.github.io/about/), if you really want to practice your embedded C/C++. But for a project as simple as EV3RSTORM, EV3Dev should be more than sufficient.